# java generic wildcards

Tags: java, generics

Currently I'm working on a service interface which retrieves domain objects based on a primary key. However I get the feeling I'm not efficiently using generics.

Base domain objects look as follows:

```
public interface DomainObject<PK extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    PK getID();
}
```

My service interface looks as follows:

```
public interface LoadService<T extends DomainObject<PK>, PK extends Serializable> {
    T load(PK ID);
}
```

This works, however I have to specify the PK type in the service generics, even though the PK type is already known inside T. Is there any way I can get around having to define my PK again in the LoadService interface? Something like:

```
LoadService<T extends DomainObject<? extends Serializable as PK> { ... }
```

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid that because you use PK class at the *'LoadService'*. I mean that you can define service like

```
interface LoadService<T extends DomainObject<?>> {
    void store(T data);
}
```

However, that's not the option if you use PK class because compiler checks that PK type is compatible with the domain object type.

Another option is to remove type parameter from *DomainObject*, i.e. perform the following:

```
interface DomainObject extends Serializable {
    Serializable getID();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using multiple bounds for the type parameter, if `T` both extends `DomainObject` and implements `Serializable`:

```
interface LoadService<T extends DomainObject<T> & Serializable> {
}
```

Comment: Try? Where's the explanation?